# Platform issue in require('os')

Tags: angular, ionic3, require, nwjs

I have created an Ionic 3(A5) app. I am running this as node-webkit (NW.JS) app on Mac. If I write inside index.html script tag and check, `require('os')` platform returns '**darwin**' and `require('fs')` returns full set of object correctly. But if I write same script inside a .ts file - `require('os')` platform returns '**browser**' and `require('fs')` returns empty object.

I am using @types/node in devDependencies.

Code inside index.html -

```
 var os = require('os');
 var fs = require('fs');
 console.log('Log from index.html');
 console.log('platform = ' + os.platform());
 console.log('fs = ');
 console.log(fs);
```

Code inside app.component.ts -

```
var os = require('os');
var fs = require('fs');
console.log('Log from app.component.ts');
console.log('platform = ' + os.platform());
console.log('fs = ');
console.log(fs);
```

[image: screenshot from nwjs console]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a reply from The Jared Wilcurt @TheJaredWilcurt on [gitter.im](http://gitter.im/nwjs),

*Node and Chromium don't know what a TS file is. you need to use something to transpile it to code that can actually be ran. TS is a meta-language, like Markdown, Sass, HAML, CoffeeScript, JSX, etc. Node only understands JavaScript, Chromium only understands HTML, CSS, and JS.
If you are using something to transpile it and it alters your require statements, then that is the problem. You should inspect the actual code you are telling the environment to run.*

This was happening because the Ionic transpiler was changing the code in some way. I changed the code

from

```
var os = require('os');
var fs = require('fs');
```

to

```
var os = nw.require('os');
var fs = nw.require('fs');
```

Now the only problem was that TypeScript compiler was not recognizing '**nw**' as it was supposed to come at runtime. I have added

```
declare var nw: any;
```

on top.
All fine now.