# os.platform returns browser instead of actual OS - React & Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron, operating-system

I am trying to retrieve the appdata folder location for the application, and since each os has a separate path for the appdata or application support folder, I tried retrieving the os type to specify which path to use. The issue is os.platform() returns 'browser'. I have tried running it on windows and mac, but they all return browser. If i run process.platform in electron.js it gives me the correct os, but in react I get browser. How can I get the proper OS?

Comment: Have you taken a look at those question? [Node/React: os.platform() returns 'browser' instead of actual OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54976123/node-react-os-platform-returns-browser-instead-of-actual-os) and [Platform issue in require('os')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49651592/platform-issue-in-requireos)

Comment: @A_A I have and they haven't provided answers that were relavent to me. The first question is the same issue as mine but no solution was provided

Answer (score 0):

In a browser you can use a combination of `navigator.platform`, `navigator.userAgent`, and `navigator.userAgentData.platform` to get the information you want, but it might take some testing and parsing.

AFAIK, `navigator.userAgentData.platform` is available only on Chrome/Chromium-based browsers, but gives the most straight-forward result when available.

Checking which platform you're using, rather than checking for specific features, is generally consider not to be a good idea -- but I've found it hard to avoid sometimes myself, especially when working around platform-specific quirks and bugs.

Comment: Yeah, I did this, it works, but the other issue is that I cannot get the home directory as I do not know the username of the user to get the correct path. os.homedir() does not work just as os.platform does not work

Comment: That is intended. The browser environment deliberately tries to hide such details.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are running `process.platform` in the renderer process.

In order to get the correct value you need to run `platform.process` either on main process (usually the background.js file) or via `@electron/remote`, like this:

```
window.require('@electron/remote').process.platform
```

`@electron/remote`'s usage depends on your electron version, I recommend you to check [@electron/remote readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@electron/remote).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Electron's [`app.getPath(name)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appgetapppath) method?

This method will return the users application data directory.

Only once the app is "ready" can you retrieve this path.

```js
// Electron module(s).
const electronApp = require('electron').app;

// Application is now ready to start.
electronApp.on('ready', () => {

    // Get the users app data directory.
    let appData = electronApp.getPath('appData');

    // Get the users home directory.
    let home = electronApp.getPath('home');
})
```